# Vagrant: dealing with requirements for a particular version of Ruby etc?

Tags: ruby, vagrant, virtualbox

I am installing a Vagrant machine from a client.

It says that it needs a particular version of Vagrant, Virtualbox, and Ruby, all of which are different from the particular versions of Vagrant, Virtualbox and Ruby required to run another vagrant machine from another client.

What can I do about this?

I would like to be able to run both VMs on my machine, but it's going to be very difficult if I have to install different versions of Vagrant/Virtualbox/Ruby each time I want to spin the VM up.

Answer (score 0):

**Best Option:** Work with your clients to make each Vagrant project compatible with the latest versions of each tool. For Vagrant at least, I don't know of too many compatibility issues from version to version, as long as the Vagrantfile is written to be somewhat "future proof". The key to Vagrant is the controlled version environment *inside* the virtual machine. That's the key benefit which lets these environments be shared among developers and on different platforms.

**Alternative:** Different Ruby versions is pretty easy with [RVM](https://rvm.io/). Different Vagrant/Virtualbox versions would be much trickier, but you might be able to install multiple versions and then wrap everything with some scripts. Vagrant under the hood calls the Virtualbox command-line utilities like VBoxManage, so it would just need to know where those are.